# How to extract name of file in a variable and check for returning value

Tags: bash, ubuntu, raspbian

I'm trying to write a little script to install the latest nodeJS version. This is how I started:

```
NODE="$(curl -sL https://nodejs.org/dist/latest | grep 'armv6l.tar.gz' | cut -d'"' -f2)" &&
wget https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/$NODE &&
tar -xzf $NODE
```

For the next steps I would need to do something like `node-v8.12.0-linux-armv6l/bin/node -v` and if this returns a value I would like to do

```
$ cd node-v8.12.0-linux-armv6l/
$ sudo cp -R * /usr/local/
```

My problem is, that `$NODE` has the complete file name - including the file extention. But for the commands I need to replace `node-v8.12.0-linux-armv6l`. Also I don't know how to check for a returning version value.

Comment: You can remove the suffix using [parameter expansion](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion) e.g. `"${NODE%.tar.gz}"`

Comment: What's sample output from `.../node -v`, and what parts do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code,

```
#!/bin/bash
SOF_PATH=/opt

NODE="$(curl -sL https://nodejs.org/dist/latest | grep 'armv6l.tar.gz' | cut -d'"' -f2)"
if [ ! -z "$NODE" ]; then
    cd $SOF_PATH
    /usr/bin/wget "https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/$NODE" >/dev/null 2>&1
    /bin/tar -xzf $NODE
    NODE_APP=${NODE%.tar.gz}
    cd $NODE_APP/bin
    NODE_VERSION=`node -v`
    echo "$NODE_VERSION"
    cd ..
    sudo cp -R * /usr/local/
fi
```

Comment: Since it's bash, you can use bash parameter substitution instead of executing a subshell to run `echo` and `awk`, like: `NODE_APP=${NODE%.tar.gz}`